# Subtracting over a range of columns for two rows in pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with six different labels: `presence`, `x`, `y`, `vx`, `vy` and `lane`. I would like to differentiate between two row indices over a range of columns [`x`, `y`, `vx`, `vy`]. However, subtracting gives me `NaN`. Thanks for the help.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'presence': [1, 1, 0, 1],
        'x': [17, 35, 46, 57],
        'y': [4, 4, 8, 0],
        'vx': [2, 5, 9, 12],
        'vy': [0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0], 
        'lane': [0, 1, 2, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
a = df.iloc[[2]]
b = df.iloc[[1]]
diff_x = b[['x','y']] - a[['x','y']] # Gives two rows and two columns of nan
# Expected output: 11  4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to you pull out the a and b as `DataFrame` not series ,

```
a
Out[312]: 
   presence   x  y  vx   vy  lane
2         0  46  8   9  0.2     2
b
Out[313]: 
   presence   x  y  vx   vy  lane
1         1  35  4   5  0.5     1
```

Above dataframe `index` is different, when we do the calculation `pandas` will check the `index` first , if index not match then output will be `NaN`

Quick fix :

```
diff_x = b[['x','y']].values - a[['x','y']].values
diff_x
Out[311]: array([[-11,  -4]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.loc` style indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to get a [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) for a certain row index and column names. Then you can subtract those two series.

If you expect to get 11 and 4 as your output, you will have to reverse your subtraction operation from your post.

```
diff_x = df.loc[2, ["x", "y"]] - df.loc[1, ["x", "y"]]

# x    11.0
# y     4.0
# dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

pandas is index oriented, convert to array and then compare:

```
a = df.iloc[[2]]
b = df.iloc[[1]]
diff_x = a[['x','y']].to_numpy() - b[['x','y']].to_numpy()
#array([[11,  4]], dtype=int64)
```

Alternatively  for 2 consecutive rows, you can use `diff`:

```
df[['x','y']].diff().iloc[2]

x    11.0
y     4.0
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```